# Definir local padrão para salvar arquivo

Tags: python

Estou criando um script em python para converter todos os arquivos de uma pasta em outro formato informado pelo usuário, porém queria pedir apenas uma vez o local para salvar o arquivos. Já tentei utilizar o askdirectory() mas dá um erro esquisito que o diretório onde estão os arquivos fica sendo o mesmo de onde eles serão salvos mesmo agregando a diferentes variáveis.

```
import glob
import img2pdf
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory


def img_to_pdf(arq, savefile):
    with open(f"{str(arq)[0:-4]}.pdf", "wb") as f:
        f.write(img2pdf.convert(arq))


def convert(filelocal, inpt, outpt, savefile):
    path = Path(str(filelocal))
    for arq in path.glob('*'):
        if arq.endswith(str(inpt)):
            if inpt == ".png" and outpt == ".pdf":
                img_to_pdf(arq, savefile)


def localfile():
    Tk().withdraw()
    filelocal = askdirectory()
    return filelocal


def filesave():
    Tk().withdraw()
    savefile = askdirectory()
    return savefile


if __name__ == '__main__':
    inpt = ".png"
    outpt = ".pdf"
    filelocal = localfile()
    savefile = filesave()
    convert(filelocal, inpt, outpt, savefile)
```

Alguma sugestão de como posso resolver esse problema? Pois as soluções que encontrei até agora só ajudam se for para salvar um único arquivo, logo, para cada arquivo dentro da pasta, ele iria pedir novamente o local. O que quero é definir um local para salvar como padrão.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que não fui muito claro com o código de exemplo, mas já consegui resolver  o problema. Se alguem tiver a mesma questão, a forma que eu fiz foi, em vez de passar um por um os arquivos para converter, a função recebe uma lista com o caminho de todos eles e a função askdirectory eu abro na própria função que vai converter, depois eu faço um loop for para ir convertendo arquivo por arquivo e movendo para a pasta de destino.

Dessa forma:

```
def img_to_pdf(arq):
    save_file = str(askdirectory(initialdir="/home"))
    for i in arq:
        fullname = str(i)[0:-4] + '.pdf'
        with open(fullname,"wb") as f:
            f.write(img2pdf.convert(str(i)))
        shutil.move(fullname, save_file)
```

para mais detalhes, o código fonte tá todo disponível e comentado em inglês no meu repositório no github: https://github.com/ThiagoA20/File-converter